# How to write Jest testcase where code includes localstorage.get/ localstorage.set

Tags: javascript, jestjs, local-storage

Im trying to write a Jest test case where code involved localstorage access.
While running test case is failing saying cant read property.

What is the way we need to write jest test case where `localstorage.getItem()` is involved

```
function myLocal(){
var value= localStorage.getItem('slot').time
return value
}
```

while running above sample code, Jest is throwing  below error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of null

Answer (score 0):

Make your function testable:

```
function getTime(storage) {
  var value = storage.getItem('slot').time
  return value
}
```

Then use it in your application like that:

```
getTime(localStorage);
```

And test it like that:

```
const mockGetItem = jest.fn();
mockGetItem.mockReturnValue({time: '16:00'});

expect(getTime({getItem: mockGetItem})).toBe('16:00');
expect(mockGetItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('slot');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But i see same object is cloned to all  items duplicated with entire local storage object.

Comment: No problem with that. You don’t need to write everywhere in your application `getTime(localStorage)` instead you could wrap it: `storage.getTime()` where storage is an instance of class or module. If you will want in future to store your data in a server instead of  localStorage you will need only change the implementation of `storage.getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

You can mock it like anything else. This example is taken from some older version of `jest-preset-angular` i think:

```js
const mock = () => {
  let storage: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  return {
    getItem: (key: string) => (key in storage ? storage[key] : null),
    setItem: (key: string, value: string) => (storage[key] = value || ''),
    removeItem: (key: string) => delete storage[key],
    clear: () => (storage = {})
  };
};

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: mock() });
Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', { value: mock() });
```

No changes in your code. Of course you have to set the items you want to get first.

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed you are using plain JavaScript, not TypeScript. In that case you have to modify the mock:

```
const mock = function() {
  const storage = {};
  return {
    getItem: (key) => (key in storage ? storage[key] : null),
    setItem: (key, value) => (storage[key] = value || ''),
    removeItem: (key) => delete storage[key],
    clear: () => (storage = {})
  };
};
```

Also, the example you posted in comments does not have a `window` object available, so you might have to mock that as well:

```
const window = {
  localStorage: mock();
};
// or if you only use localStorage without window, this might suffice:
localStorage = mock();
```

Comment: Hello @Markus Dresch. Tried your solution, but getting some errors,  could you please check this and provide me a  running example please https://repl.it/repls/ExcitedUprightScientists

Comment: what errors do you get? see https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-czggwv

Comment: i updated the post with a plain javascript version. didn't see the tag and your example for some reason, sorry.